# Image Retrieve using c#

Tags: c#, image, stream

```
byte[] imageData = null;
long byteSize = 0;
byteSize = _reader.GetBytes(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName), 0, null, 0, 0);

imageData = new byte[byteSize];
long bytesread = 0;
int curpos = 0, chunkSize = 500;
while (bytesread < byteSize)
{
    // chunkSize is an arbitrary application defined value 
    bytesread += _reader.GetBytes(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName), curpos, imageData, curpos, chunkSize);
    curpos += chunkSize;
}

byte[] imgData = imageData;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
Image oImage = Image.FromStream((Stream)ms);
return oImage;
```

Code creates problem when `"Image oImage = Image.FromStream((Stream)ms);"` line executes.....This line shows `"Parameter is not valid"` message .......Why it occurs? Help me. I want to retrieve image from database ....I work on C# window vs05 .....Can any one help me? byte[] contain value. All works well, just problem occurs when this line executes.

Comment: Have your verified that the byte array does indeed contain data?

Answer (score 1):

A simple if statement should solve your problem before creating the memory stream

```
if (imageData.Length != 0)
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
  Image oImage = Image.FromStream((Stream)ms);
  return oImage;
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really spot any errors in this code (other than the MemoryStream not being disposed, and that it's not necessary to cast it to `Stream` when passing it to the `Image.FromStream` method; but those should not cause your error). I would do the following in order to try to find the error:

- Write the byte data to a file and try to open the image in a graphics program (to verify that the byte data does indeed represent a valid image). My guess is that this would fail.
- Check the code that writes the data to the database (perhaps perform the same trick as in the previous point; write it to a file and try to open the file)